# VS Community - Cannot run a simple console application: Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Reflection.Metadata'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, badimageformatexception, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I’ve installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.4 and tried to create a simple console application to print “Hello World”.

If I run the app with `dotnet run` from the Windows Command Prompt, it will run successfully, but opening the project in VS and trying to start the console app is causing the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ or one of its dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570)
```

I’ve already tried to start the console app as x86 and x64, but that did not help.

Another attempt was to uninstall **VS 2019** and install **VS 2017 Community**. Have the same exception when I build the console app.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570)
```

Could someone please help me with this?